# I've written some code in the main() function. I actually want to keep that code in a user defined function and call that in the main function

Tags: c, function

My CODE:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int num,codeword1[num],codeword2[num],counter=0;
    
    printf("Enter the length of the Codeword: ");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    printf("Enter the 1st Codeword:\n");
    for(int i=0;i<num;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&codeword1[i]);
    }
    printf("\nEnter the 2nd Codeword:\n");
    for(int i=0;i<num;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&codeword2[i]);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<num;i++)
    {
        if(codeword1[i]!=codeword2[i])
        {
            counter=counter+1;
        }
        else
        {
            continue;
        }
        
    }
    printf("\n\nThe Number of codewords mismatched are:");
    if(counter>0)
    {
        printf("%d",counter);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("0");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I want to create a function and keep the logic of the code in it and later I want to call that function in the main() function. How do I do it ?

Comment: Are you asking "what is the syntax for writing a function?"

Comment: Yes. How to proceed from here ?

Comment: Note that `int num, codeword1[num], codeword2[num], counter = 0;` will be *undefined behaviour*. You need to enter a value for `num` *before* the array is allocated.

Comment: In the simplest form, 1) rename `main` to `my_func`, 2) write a new `main` that calls it.

Comment: @VaibavReddy This isn't a place to ask about the basics of programming, I'd suggest finding a good book or tutorial to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Simply change the name of your main function nto the desired function name.
for instance

```
int something(void); /*since your main doesn't take any input, the function input should be void*/
```

Then create another main function and call your function from there. If they are not to be in the same file, remember to create a header file with a prototype of your function.

```
int main(void)
{
    int return_from_something;
    return_from_something = something(void);
    
   return (0);
}
```